# Вызов браузера

Tags: android

Нужно, чтобы нажав на кнопку в приложении, осуществлялся переход на определенную страницу через браузер. Как это реализовать? Было бы неплохо увидеть пример кода...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Если вы хотите вызвать стороний браузер, то.

```
Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browser);
```

2) Если вы хотите разместить вьюшку браузера в своем приложении, то.

```
WebView web = new WebView(this);     // this - ваше текущее активити  
rootLayout.addView(web);  
web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Во этом случае не забудьте добавить строчку

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

в манифест файл.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как в андроиде, а просто в джаве я делаю так

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://ya.ru"));
```

Вызывается браузер по умолчанию.